# Assembly x86 sign flag

Tags: assembly, x86

Why would the below instructions set the sign flag?

```
mov al,0FEh
sub al,2
```

As I understand it the AL register can hold 2^8 - 1 or 255. 0FEh = 254 in decimal. Subtracting 2 leaves 252. This seems to be positive.

**(For those new to assembly/binary arithmetic, below may clarify the accepted answer)**

```
dec = bin
254 = 1111 1110
      0000 0001 <- inverted bits
      0000 0001 <- add 1
      0000 0010 <- two's complement value (happens to = -2 --
                   this has nothing to do with the name two's complement)
```

Comment: [Intel's Architecture Manual](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) says: "*Sign bit - set equal to the most-significant bit of the result.*"

Comment: "set the msb to indicate negative" is not a step, unless you're converting to sign-magnitude representation (but, why). What you've done with the first two steps is negate 254, proving that it is also known as -2 (no surprises there, 254 is obviously 2 less than 256). Suddenly flipping the sign bit is equivalent to adding (or subtracting) 128.

Comment: @harold thanks. I realized I confused sign extension here, if we had a larger register all the values to the left would be 1s right? In the example above, how does the sign get preserved if the value is stored since we'd no longer have the sign flag to differentiate 254 in an unsigned 8 bits from -2 in a signed 8 bits?

Comment: In this example, 254 and -2 are merely two interpretations of the same bit vector (do some math with them in 8 bits, you'll see why they are the same, eg 254+7=5). They cannot be distinguished in this form. If there were more bits there would still be such a "duality" between big numbers and negative numbers, but the affected numbers would be higher.

Comment: So then the data type (signed vs unsigned) must always be explicitly signified by some other flag. Do you know how the data type is passed in to the CPU so that it knows to set the sign flag?

Comment: @auerbachb it's even simpler, it always makes the sign flag a copy of the top bit. For unsigned numbers that just doesn't mean "negative".

Comment: @harold sorry, I did a bad job of communicating my question. I get that the sign flag is set via the top bit (since the negative numbers will always have this bit as 1), but what I was curious about is how does it distinguish signed from unsigned numbers before it even receives a value? Is there another memory cell used to store some kind of marker for the data type? (That might not be totally clear, sorry if my lack of knowledge is impeding my question again!)

Comment: @auerbachb in the cases where it matters (which is almost never, for example `sub` works exactly the same way for signed input as for unsigned input), it's in the instruction. For example `div` vs `idiv`, or `jb` vs `jl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sign flag assumes that the operand is treated as a signed (2's complement) value.

In the case of AL, that means it's viewed as holding values from -128 to +127.

0feh, when treated as a signed, 8-bit quantity represents -2. Subtracting 2 gives 0fch, which (again, as a signed, 8-bit quantity) is -4.

When/if you choose to, you can view AL as holding values from 0 to 255. When you do so, however, you're treating AL as unsigned. When you're dealing with unsigned values, you're generally going to ignore the sign flag--it's simply irrelevant to unsigned arithmetic.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. My reference was not explicit. Now I'm sure. Thank you for clarifying!